# Error when building TclTk in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tcl

i have troubles to compile Tcl/Tk with Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.x). I can compile the code from 2010 to 2013.

I get the folowing error when compiling the tkStubLib.c file with msvc 2017

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\winnt.h(20062): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'`

I tried TclTk 8.6.0 and 8.6.8

Does anybody can help me?

Comment: The Tcl and Tk source code distributions don't supply that file. It's only mentioned as an explicit dependency when building `tcl/win/tclWinInit.c`, and we never `#define constant` to be anything either. I can't probe further; I don't have a Windows build system set up at all.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9923628/301832) looks relevant, but I can't tell if it is a duplicate or not.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.tcl/2u1UopML7h0/UWA00xhCAAAJ and https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview?name=3d34589aa0 .  Not sure why the fix did not make it into 8.6.8.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. That's an interesting problem. Does anybody know if i can mix the windows sdk's in different libs, f.e. when one lib use win sdk v1 and the other lib using lib one with win sdk v2? Because it would be easier at the moment to the vcvarsall the win sdk which works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vcvarsall x64 10.0.15063.0
```

to set up a 64-bit build environment (x86 for 32-bit).

Reference: http://wiki.tcl.tk/54819

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `tk/xlib/X11/X.h` defines macros `None` and `ControlMask`. And these words just happen to be used in Windows SDK headers since SDK `10.0.16299.0` as identifiers. So they get replaced, breaking those headers, if `<windows.h>` gets #include'd after `X.h` (or any headers that include it, all the way up to `tk.h`).

This has been reported under [Tk Source Code: Tk does not build under Visual Studio 2017 Update 5](https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/3d34589aa0ae079039e2).

---

The simplest fix is to search & rename these macros across the Tk codebase -- e.g. to `None_` and `ControlMask_`:

```sh
$ find ! \( -path './.git/*' -o -type d \) -a \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \) -print0 |\
xargs -0 python -c '
import sys,re
for fname in sys.argv[1:]:
 with open(fname,"rb") as f: l=f.read()
 (r,n)=re.subn(r"\b(None|ControlMask)\b",r"\1_",l)
 if n>0:
  with open(fname,"wb") as f: f.write(r)
'
```

This will make the resulting Tk headers incompatible with normal ones. Though it only matters if you have other programs that will need to be compiled against the Tk C interface. Besides, you can rename them back in the tree resulting from `buildall.vc.bat install`.

Comment: This works like a charm. Indeed the accepted answer did not work for me. And apparently even after changing the Tcl&Tk version from 8.6.8 to 8.6.9 or even 8.7.a1, the error had persisted. After replace the macros, tk compiles.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problems. Using an older SDK version might not be the best answer. If you are interested in a more robust solution, you can read my answer [here](https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/fcfd9a84d424e878ea03759d2776003dc27e7b3b).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to add `#include <windows.h>` to `tk/xlib/X11/X.h`.
This ensures `windows.h` get included before `X.h`.

```
/*
 *  $XConsortium: X.h,v 1.66 88/09/06 15:55:56 jim Exp $
 */

/* Definitions for the X window system likely to be used by applications */

#ifndef X_H
#define X_H
/* patched, include "windows.h" first to avoid conflict macro */
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#   include <windows.h>
#   undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue, but turns out my reason for it was a noob mistake.

Don't accidentally write this line into your own code:

```
#define X
```

It will mess up VC libraries.